# Files arent autogenerating in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, migration, migrate

recently I have noticed that my app no longer autogenerates files from gems and migrations, etc.  Right now I want to run a rails g migration and in the console it says that the table has been created.  However when I look on sublime text I dont see the file in db/migrate.  Its been created but doesnt show up automatically in sublime. Is there a setting I changed? I recently deployed the app with production. Thank you!!

[image]

Comment: Please post errors as text, not images.

Comment: Maybe you're creating the file somewhere else. Have a look for it, or quit and relaunch Sublime as it might be confused.